# Laravel accessing image in Storage folder on WAMP

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel accessing image in Storage folder is working on live server but it is not working on the local server (below is the error)

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Have you ran `php artisan storage:link` ?

Comment: there are too many redirects some times it happens if your projects is not installed correctly on local server first you should try clear you cookies